# Fortran: Writing and Reading Formatted Files

Tags: file, fortran

I have an array of floating point numbers and want to write the values to a file. Then read them back.

I am writing to the file as follows

```
Do k = 1, nk
  Do j = 1, nj
    Write (u,*) (lec(i,j,k), i = 1, ni)
  End Do
End Do
```

This writes the numbers as follows when 
`ni = 5`, `nj = 4` and `nk = 2`.

```
1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5    
2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5
3.1 3.2 3.3 3.4 3.5
4.1 4.2 4.3 4.4 4.5
1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5    
2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5
3.1 3.2 3.3 3.4 3.5
4.1 4.2 4.3 4.4 4.5
```

I want to change the format of the output file in the following way

```
lec: 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5    
+ 2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5
+ 3.1 3.2 3.3 3.4 3.5
+ 4.1 4.2 4.3 4.4 4.5
+ 1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5    
+ 2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5
+ 3.1 3.2 3.3 3.4 3.5
+ 4.1 4.2 4.3 4.4 4.5
```

How can I modify the code to get this form of output?

I read things the same way, but I read the values in lec only when I encounter key `lec:` in the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Do k = 1, nk
   Do j = 1, nj
     if(k.eq.1.and.j.eq.1)then
       write(u,'(a)',advance='no')'lec:'
     else
       write(u,'(a)',advance='no')'+'
     endif
     Write (u,*) (lec(i,j,k), i = 1, ni)
   End Do
  End Do
```

or

```
 Do k = 1, nk
   Do j = 1, nj
     if(k.eq.1.and.j.eq.1)then
       write(u,'(a,99f4.1))'lec:',(lec(i,j,k), i = 1, ni)
     else
       write(u,'(a,99f4.1)')'+',(lec(i,j,k), i = 1, ni)
     endif      
   End Do
  End Do
```

the `99` can be any number larger than `ni`  or `*` if your compiler supports it.

Comment: Note that with `*` an extra set of `()` will be needed.

Comment: Now I have to read the file and fill up `lec`. However I only fill the array when I encounter `lec:` inside the file and continue reading remaining lines that start with `+`. Then stop when a blank line is reached or another key such as `Newkey:` is encountered.

Comment: you need to read each line as a string, check the key tag and internal read the rest.  Its not difficult but I wonder why you've invented a file format that's not so nice to read/write.

Comment: @francescalus one of these days my sysadmin will upgrade my compiler so I can actually test that!!

Comment: One problem is that the line can be extremely long, and would have to have a very long string